# Column header is getting removed after standard scaling

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm applying standard scaling to a data frame as shown in the below code. But it is printing the column headers as numbers.

```
scaler = StandardScaler()

data = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=df.columns) 

scaler.fit(data)

scaled = scaler.transform(data)

scaled_data = pd.DataFrame(scaled)

scaled_data.head
```

[image]

But I want the column headers to be displayed with actual column header names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the no. of columns is same in both dataframes(data and scaled_data)

Use:-

```
scaled_data = pd.DataFrame(scaled)
scaled_data.columns=data.columns
```